# cipher.update() returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a message. But cipher.update() returns null (The console.log at the end doesn't print anything).The code used:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)
let key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('MyKey').digest('hex').slice(0,32)
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc',key,iv)
encryptedPassword = cipher.update('encrypt this message','utf-8','hex')
console.log(encryptedPassword)
```

I can't understand why this is so. I followed instructions from [this](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options) docs. I am new to nodejs, If I have missed something, do correct me. Thanks!

Comment: that code shows output for me - are you sure that's **exactly** the code you are running?

Comment: In my code, I had two variables passed in place of 'MyKey' and 'encrypt this message'. I replaced them here to make the code presentable. But now that you say it, I tested out this exact snippet and obtained correct output. But further testing, I discovered that the output is null when the message passed in cipher.update() is small, like 'hello' and 'helloworld', but obtains output for longer strings, like 'helloworldthisisatest'. Turns out output is obtained for strings of length >=16. Why is this and how do I resolve this?

Comment: that what `cipher.final('hex')` is for

Comment: look in that page you linked to ... search for *Example: Using the cipher.update() and cipher.final() methods:*

Comment: Thank you, appending encryptedPassword with `cipher.final('hex')` solved the problem.