# empty result from crypto.update() + crypto.final()

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to encrypt a pdf file before uploading in IPFS but I'm getting a null value in update(). I already have .final() appended after .update() like the solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324875/cipher-update-returns-null) but it's still not working. Here's the code I'm using to encrypt the file:

```
const encrypt = () => {
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    
    const data = userinput.files[0];

    //compute hash and iv
    const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data).digest('base64').substring(0,32);
    
    //encrypt
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    const result = iv + cipher.update(data) + cipher.final();

    return result;
}
```

and this is how I got the file from the user:

```
<form>
    <label for="userinput" class="form-label">Upload Document</label>
    <div class="mb-4 input-group">
         <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="userinput" id="userinput">
    </div>
</form>
```

Edit:

I edited the code above and this is how it looks now:

```
const encrypt = () => {
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    
    const data = userinput.files[0];

    //compute hash and iv
    const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data).digest('base64').substring(0,32);
    
    //encrypt
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    const result = Buffer.concat([iv, cipher.update(data), cipher.final()]);

    return result;
}
```

I'm only getting a 16 bytes binary data from iv. I'm not sure why update() and final() is returning an empty value.  I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@anned20/encrypting-files-with-nodejs-a54a0736a50a).

Comment: `iv`, `cipher.update(data)` and `cipher.final()` are buffers and must be concatenated with `Buffer.concat([...])`. Alternatively all three parts can be converted to byte strings with `latin1` as encoding and concatenated with `+`. For the latter for `update()` and `final()` the input/output encodings have to be specified.

Comment: Hi @Topaco! I did this but I'm getting an error. I edited the post so I could give more information about it :)

Comment: I said *alternatively*. You have mixed both approaches! Either you concatenate as buffer, i.e. *without* input/output encoding, or you concatenate as string (with latin1 encoding), i.e. *with* input/output encoding. In the latter case you also have to convert the IV with latin1 into a string.

Comment: okay, my bad. I edited it now and I'm only getting a 16 bytes binary data from the iv. I'm not getting data from the `update(), final()`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Check `data`, maybe this is empty. By the way: Taking the plaintext `data` as key material is illogical, because then the receiving side would have to know `data` (for key derivation) before encryption.

Comment: I checked in the console and it's not empty. It printed this `File {name: 'Sample.pdf', ... }` @Topaco

Comment: Then maybe something is wrong with your environment. For a non-empty `data` the ciphertext is generated as expected: https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/rDK

Comment: I tried encrypting a string though and it's working just fine. But if I go back and encrypt a pdf file, it returns an empty value. I'm not sure why this is the case. @Topaco

Comment: For encryption it doesn't matter if string, text file or .pdf file, only bytes are encrypted. I can't reproduce the problem either, i.e. on my machine no problem encrypting a .pdf file (as expected). Try to encrypt a text file, then a small .pdf file and so on. Maybe you will find out this way what you are doing wrong.

Comment: okay I'll try this. Thank you! @Topaco